# access to categorial variables inside tapply

Tags: r

I have a data-frame with 2 (or more) categorial variables and one observation.
I want to produce boxplots for those combinations of the categorial variables, for which the number of observations is higher than a certain threshold. The idea is to have a plot-file with a series of  boxplots, each plot named after the combination of the categorial variables defining the relevant subset.

My idea is to use `tapply` on a self-defined function. This works in principle (see below). My only problem is, that I do not know to access the relevant combination of categorial variables as title of the plot inside the function. **How do I have access to them?

current solution:

```
cat1 <- c("A","A","A","A","E")
cat2 <- c("a","c","c","c","e")
obs  <- c(2.0,2.2,2.5,5.0,1.0)

my_plot <- function(obs_subset,??_cat1-val,cat2-val_??) {
  if(length(obs_subset) > 2) boxplot(obs_subset,
     main=paste(cat1-val,cat2-val,sep = " ")) ;# how to compute the title 
}
 indices <- list(cat1,cat2)

 pdf(file="theFileName.pdf")
 tapply(obs,indices,my_plot)
 dev.off()
```

It works without the values of the categorial variables.
How can I get access to the actual values of cat1 and cat2 in the respective calls so that they can be used to label the plots?

Comment: I think you need to describe your intended output better...how do you plan to make multiple boxplots from a subset of one variable?

Comment: Thanks, the solution of Sven H. worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a numeric index along `obs` and use it inside `tapply`:

```
idx <- seq_along(obs)
```

The index is used to extract values from `obs`, `cat1`, and `cat2`:

```
my_plot <- function(obs_idx) {
  if(length(obs[obs_idx]) > 2) 
    boxplot(obs[obs_idx],
            main = paste(cat1[obs_idx[1]], 
                         cat2[obs_idx[1]])) 
}
```

Now, you can use `tapply`. I recommend using `invisible` if you're not interested in the values returned by `tapply`.

```
pdf(file = "theFileName.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
invisible(tapply(idx, indices, my_plot))
dev.off()
```